# echo Session array value- warning Illegal string offset

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm trying to add cart function into a websites using SESSION, the items were store into SESSION but i have this Warning: Illegal string offset 'pcode' when i try to echo out the array value

```
$itemArray = array('pcode'=>$_GET['code']);
$_SESSION['cart_item'] = $itemArray;
```

This is how i store the array into session

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart_item'] as $item){
                echo $item['pcode'];
                }
```

and this is how i echo my store array. I'm quite new to PHP and have been trying to build a websites from scratch. I wonder why the WARNING keep on showing on my page. thanks

Comment: Try this foreach ($_SESSION['cart_item'] as $key=>$item){
                echo $key.'-->'.$item;
                }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only $item will give you value:

```
$itemArray = array('pcode'=>'aaa');
$_SESSION['cart_item'] = $itemArray;
foreach ($_SESSION['cart_item'] as $key=>$item){
    echo $key; // this will print "pcode"
    echo $item; // this will print "aaa"
}
```

To append data into session:

```
$data = $_SESSION['cart_item']; // first get session data into any array
$data['newdata'] = 'newvalue'; // now add data 
$_SESSION['cart_item'] = $data; // again write session with newly added array
```

Comment: Thanks! I get the idea and its working now. Btw every time when i try to add a new item into the  $_SESSION['cart_item'] it seems to overwrite the previous items, anyway to solve this?

Comment: how you are adding data to session>??

Comment: $itemArray = array('pcode'=>'aaa');
$_SESSION['cart_item'] = $itemArray; the same way i posted, but i think i need a 2 dimensional array is that correct?

Comment: @kojh i have updated answer above for appending data into session..try that

Comment: thanks for ur help, but i used array_merge() to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

`echo $item` you will get the $item['pcode'] value as you are using foreach which gives you key => value pair, so 'pcode' is key and $_GET['code'] its value in foreach and since you are only using $item it will point to value which is $_GET['code'].

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GET['code']='www';
$itemArray = array('pcode'=>$_GET['code']);
$_SESSION['cart_item'] = $itemArray;
foreach ($_SESSION['cart_item'] as $item){
                echo $item;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no key with `pcode` in your array item.

There is a method to check if there is any key or not  `array_key_exists`

```
bool array_key_exists ( mixed $key , array $array )
```

Any easier approach to find the contents is to print the array and die, see if the contents of array, fix and try again.